# Store a function on server with Java - MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using Java driver for MongoDB (***mongo-java-driver-2.13.0***). 
I need to store a function, called `my_function`, on server. 
From MongoDB shell I used the following code:

```
> db.system.js.save( { _id : "function1", value : my_function } );
```

I need this function to use it in a map-reduce. 
How can I store the function using Java driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer all to myself, maybe it can be useful for someone.
You don't need to save your function on server. 
Suppose I have to use a javascript function `foo` in map-reduce. You can follow this example:

```
    String map = "function(){" 
                  + "foo = function(parameters) {...here you have to write foo code...}
                  + ".....now you can use foo function in your map reduce......."
```

So, just define in map function your function `foo` and then you will be able to you it inside your map reduce code.