# Load js script using java - MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

In MongoDB shell one can use `db.loadServerScripts()` command to load all scripts in the `system.js` collection for the current database. Then one can use functions in `system.js` collection for `map-reduce` or `$where`.

For example:

```
foo = function (parameters) .................foo code..................
db.system.js.save( { _id : "foo", value : foo } );
```

Now one can use `foo` in `map-reduce`.

How can I define a `foo` function to use it in a map-reduce using Java driver?

Comment: This basically never works how some people seem to expect it does. If you have code that actually "runs on the server" ( say via `mapReduce` or by `eval()` ) then you can reference that code and use it. Something like `.loadServerScripts()` only works in the shell because it is itself a JavaScript REPL, and therefore understands JavaScript. So this is reall of no use to you in another language, unless you similarly want to load in a JavaScript runtime. In all likelihood, the "how you intend to use your 'sum'" would also not be valid, and therefore you would code the real solution differently.

Comment: I edited my previous question. Now it is not a duplicate of what you suggested. At the most of one of my other questions: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063323/store-a-function-on-server-with-java-mongodb/35387823#35387823). 
Maybe you can edit the linked duplicate question.

Comment: How would this not be a duplicate? I see nothing in here that is asking anything really different, or more importantly does not end up with the same basic answer. You can of course "call" server stored JavaScript in `$where` or mapReduce, but you still need to send basic JavaScript code ( either special object for driver or just a string as argument, driver dependant ) as the basic "meat" of either the `$where` or mapReduce invocation itself. So for the driver driver (  according to documentation ) the arguments for JavaScript code would be a `String`.